# Non-selective query against large object type (more than 100000 rows) in Visual Flow

Tags: flow

I am working on visual Flows and using Fast Lookup and Record Lookup in flows where I added following filters:-
[image]

When I run this flow as a System Admin by clicking "run" button it works fine but when I run this by site user then getting following exception:-
"*System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large object type (more than 100000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or contact salesforce.com about custom indexing.
Even if a field is indexed a filter might still not be selective when:
1. The filter value includes null (for instance binding with a list that contains null)
2. Data skew exists whereby the number of matching rows is very large (for instance, filtering for a particular foreign key value that occurs many times)*"

Anybody have any idea how to resolve this issue, I already used Index field in filer "Contact_AutoNumber__c" and there approx more than 100000 records.

I would be very grateful for your help and advice.
Thanks

Comment: looks like you are filtering phone twice. phone is null and phone equals {!Phone_Number}. Probably the filter phone is null is not required.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is due to the fact you are putting filter on null fields and you have a large amount of data being returned by the query.

- Any query which returns more than 10% of the total records will be
  considered as **Non-Selective**.
- If you run a non-selective query on an object which has more than 100000 records, you will see this error.
- You should include indexed fields in the WHERE clause to avoid
  these exceptions.
- To index fields, you can either mark those fields
  as 'External ID' here you can make the phone number field Indexed by
  making it external ID (*Not Possible here as it is a standard field*).
- You can contact salesforce support by creating a support case to
  create custom indexes on your fields based on your query.

Hope this helps :)

Thank You!

Comment: I put filters on field to exclude nulls from search result, I tried by running this in developer console and its working fine. making Phone as Index is final solution but I want if I can fix this without making Phone as Indexed.